# How to copy a page from one process to another in linux?

Tags: memory-management, paging

I have two processes. I want to copy a few pages of one process to another process such that the values of variables in first process become equal to values of variables of the second process whose pages are copied.

I am not looking for fork. I just want to copy a particular page from one process to another and want the first process to point to same memory area as the other process.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want memmap. Unfortunately, memmap does so many things and I don't know exactly what you want to do so I cannot tell you what setting you ned to use. It would depend upon exactly who you want to use things.